# Logging level string not correct in sub-modules

Tags: python, logging

I am working with the standard library logging module and just came across something I cannot explain: namely, that when I get a logger from a sub-module it appears that the string associated with the logger's level is `WARNING`, no matter what logging level it is actually set to. Even more confusingly, the sub-module logger logs messages at the correct level. If you run `main.py` below (changing the log filename first), you'll see what I mean. The console prints that the logger level at other_module is `WARNING` but it records the lower-level messages faithfully.

I actually kind of need the string associated with the level for something, if I can get at it. Is this behavior a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

**main.py**

```
import logging
import other_module

def create_logger(log_level):
    level = log_level.upper()
    switcher = {"DEBUG": logging.DEBUG,
                "INFO": logging.INFO,
                "WARNING": logging.WARNING,
                "ERROR": logging.ERROR,
                "CRITICAL": logging.CRITICAL}
    logging.basicConfig(filename='C:/logs/log.log', #Change this
                        format="%(asctime)s | %(name)s [Line %(lineno)d] | %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
                        datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                        level=switcher[level])
    logger = logging.getLogger("root")
    return logger

def main():
    log = create_logger('DEBUG')
    log.debug("Message from main")
    other_module.test_function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**other_module.py**

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print("other_module log level is {}".format(logging.getLevelName(log.getEffectiveLevel())))

def test_function():
    log.debug('Message from other_module')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `other_module.py` was loaded before the logging system was configured and its logger is instantiated using default values.

If you put the `basicConfig` call before `import other_module` the logging level will be as intended.

Comment: Ok so I can't believe I didn't try that earlier. It worked to move the import into the main function. However I'm still puzzled about why the call to `log.debug()` inside of `test_function` works when you have them in my original order? If the details on the global sub-module logger are set when you get the logger at module import, then how do those get changed once `test_function` actually gets run? Does this make sense?

Comment: The logging level is actually changed but your print statement is executed before the configuration. Try to put the same print statement inside the test_function.

Comment: There is some dark magic afoot here, but that is par for the course for the logging module as far as I can gather. Thank you.

Comment: Some time ago I was bitten by a similar problem relating to config not working after loggers were already instantiated, so yes still some magic lurking in this module.